# Constructing a Complex SQL Query with Joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry for the nondescript title but I'm not sure how to phrase the question. Say we have the following tables:

```
    people
    id|created_at|updated_at|name             |
    --|----------|----------|-----------------|
     1|          |          |Quentin Tarantino|
     2|          |          |Terry O'Quinn    | 
     3|          |          |Sam Jackson      |
     4|          |          |Michael Madsen   |
     5|          |          |Bryan Cranston   |

    crew_members
    id|created_at|updated_at|type    |
    --|----------|----------|--------|
     1|          |          |Actor   |
     2|          |          |Director|
     3|          |          |Writer  |

    movies
    id|created_at|updated_at|title         |
    --|----------|----------|--------------|
     1|          |          |Pulp Fiction  |
     2|          |          |Reservoir Dogs|

    series
    id|created_at|updated_at|title             |
    --|----------|----------|------------------|
     1|          |          |Lost              |
     2|          |          |Breaking Bad      |
     3|          |          |The Tarantino Show|

    credits
    id|created_at|updated_at|person_id|character   |crew_member_id|
    --|----------|----------|---------|------------|--------------|
     1|          |          |        1|            |             2|
     2|          |          |        1|Jimmy       |             1|
     3|          |          |        1|            |             3|
     4|          |          |        2|John Locke  |             1|
     5|          |          |        3|Jules       |             1|
     6|          |          |        4|Mr Blonde   |             1|
     7|          |          |        5|Walter White|             1|
     8|          |          |        1|Mr Brown    |             1|
     9|          |          |        1|Himself       |             1|

    credit_feature_person
    id|created_at|updated_at|person_id|credit_id|movie_id|series_id|
    --|----------|----------|---------|---------|--------|---------|
     1|          |          |        1|        1|       1|        0|
     2|          |          |        1|        2|       1|        0|
     3|          |          |        1|        3|       1|        0|
     4|          |          |        1|        1|       2|        0|
     5|          |          |        1|        8|       2|        0|
     6|          |          |        1|        3|       2|        0|
     7|          |          |        2|        4|       0|        1|
     8|          |          |        3|        5|       1|        0|
     9|          |          |        4|        6|       2|        0|
    10|          |          |        5|        7|       0|        2|
    11|          |          |        1|        9|       0|        3|
```

If I want to show all movies a person (say, Tarantino with id 1) was involved in, plus what they did in that movie, I can do this:

```
    select m.title as movie, coalesce(character,type) as role 
    from "credits" 
    inner join "credit_feature_person" on "credits"."id" = "credit_id" 
    inner join "people" on "credit_feature_person"."person_id" = "people"."id" 
    inner join "movies" m on "credit_feature_person"."movie_id" = "m"."id"
    inner join "crew_members" on "credits"."crew_member_id" = "crew_members"."id"
    where "credits"."person_id" = 1;

    //result
         movie      |   role   
    ----------------+----------
     Pulp Fiction   | Director
     Pulp Fiction   | Jimmy
     Pulp Fiction   | Writer
     Reservoir Dogs | Director
     Reservoir Dogs | Mr Brown
     Reservoir Dogs | Writer
    (6 rows)
```

But I also want to include the series they worked on too, and the result to look like

```
         title      |   role   
    ----------------+----------
     Pulp Fiction   | Director
     Pulp Fiction   | Jimmy
     Pulp Fiction   | Writer
     Reservoir Dogs | Director
     Reservoir Dogs | Mr Brown
     Reservoir Dogs | Writer
    The Tarantino Show | Himself
    (7 rows)
```

I keep trying different things and either get syntax errors or 0 results. Any ideas? I expected to at least be able to do this:

```
    select coalesce(m.title, s.title) as title, coalesce(character,type) as role 
    from "credits" 
    inner join "credit_feature_person" on "credits"."id" = "credit_id" 
    inner join "people" on "credit_feature_person"."person_id" = "people"."id" 
    inner join "movies" m on "credit_feature_person"."movie_id" = "m"."id"
    inner join "series" s on "credit_feature_person"."series_id" = "s"."id"
    inner join "crew_members" on "credits"."crew_member_id" = "crew_members"."id"
    where "credits"."person_id" = 1;
```

But this doesn't work either, it returns zero results for some reason.

Edit:
Solution is to use left joins on movies and series

```
select coalesce(m.title,s.title) as title, coalesce(character,type) as role 
from "credits" 
inner join "credit_feature_person" on "credits"."id" = "credit_id" 
inner join "people" on "credit_feature_person"."person_id" = "people"."id" 
left join "movies" m on "credit_feature_person"."movie_id" = "m"."id"
left join "series" s on "credit_feature_person"."series_id" = "s"."id"
inner join "crew_members" on "credits"."crew_member_id" = "crew_members"."id"
where "credits"."person_id" = 1;
```

Comment: Try to change `inner join` to `left join`

Comment: If movie and series are mutually exclusive, as I think they are, you won't want inner joins to both of them.

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto that works! I also realized I could just copy the original query, modify it to return series, then union the two together with select coalesce(m.title,s.title) as title

Comment: @clem You don't want all of them to be outer joins.

Comment: @shawnt00 I'm now doing inner joins on credit_feature_person, people, and crew_members and left joins on movies and series. Is that a problem?

Comment: Since you mentioned Abelisto in your comment it seemed likely that you changed them all to inner join. Both of your options sound valid to me.

Comment: Here is a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45440/5

Comment: @shawnt00 nice! Thanks so much

Comment: @shawnt00 having gone to that effort you should post it as an answer.

Comment: PS: Note that the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional in most modern DBMS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the links to movies and series are mutually exclusive. When you attempt an inner join to the one side that's missing each of the rows is eliminated from the results. Those two joins need to be left outer joins.

```
select coalesce(m.title, s.title) as title, coalesce(character,type) as role 
from "credits" 
    inner join "credit_feature_person" on "credits"."id" = "credit_id" 
    inner join "people" on "credit_feature_person"."person_id" = "people"."id" 
    inner join "crew_members" on "credits"."crew_member_id" = "crew_members"."id"
    left outer join "movies" m on "credit_feature_person"."movie_id" = "m"."id"
    left outer join "series" s on "credit_feature_person"."series_id" = "s"."id"
    where "credits"."person_id" = 1
order by title, role;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45440/5